# how to select particular data from min to max in sql

Tags: mysql

my table is as

```
price 
10
20
30
40 
50
70
90
100
```

when i pass two parameters `@min= 10` and `@max=90` 
then i have the result data like

```
10
20
30
40
50
70
90
```

Comment: Please, be clear. What result do you want to get?

Comment: The Selected Data is between min to Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT price FROM table WHERE price BETWEEN @min and @max
```

or

```
SELECT price FROM table WHERE price >= @min and price <= @max
```

or, if you want this as comma-separated string

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(", " price) FROM table WHERE price >= @min and price <= @max
```

Answer (score 0):

> select price from table where price between @min and @max